# Dumping SQL table to .csv C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, csv

I am trying to implement a script in my application that will dump the entire contents (for now, but I am trying to write the code so that I can easily customize it to only grab certain columns) of a sql db (running ms sql server express 2014) to a .csv file.

Here is the code I have written currently:

```
        public void doCsvWrite(string timeStamp){       
        try {
            //specify file name of log file (csv).
            string newFileName = "C:/TestDirectory/DataExport-" + timeStamp + ".csv";
            //check to see if file exists, if not create an empty file with the specified file name.
            if (!File.Exists(newFileName)) {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
                fs.Close();
                //define header of new file, and write header to file.
                string csvHeader = "ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3,ITEM4,ITEM5";
                using (FileStream fsWHT = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                using(StreamWriter swT = new StreamWriter(fsWHT))
                {
                    swT.WriteLine(csvHeader.ToString());
                }
            }
            //set up connection to database.
            SqlConnection myDEConnection;   
            String cDEString = "Data Source=localhost\\NAMEDPIPE;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=user;Password=pwd";
            String strDEStatement = "SELECT * FROM table"; 

            try
            {
                myDEConnection = new SqlConnection(cDEString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                //error handling here.
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                myDEConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //error handling here.
                return;
            }
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            SqlCommand myDECommand = new SqlCommand(strDEStatement, myDEConnection);
            try
            {
                reader = myDECommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        if(reader["Column1"].ToString() == "") {
                            //does nothing if the current line is "bugged" (containing no values at all, typically happens after reboot of 3rd party equipment).
                        }
                        else {
                            //grab relevant tag data and set the csv line for the current row.
                            string csvDetails = reader["Column1"] + "," + reader["Column2"] + "," + String.Format("{0:0.0}", reader["Column3"]) + "," + String.Format("{0:0.000}", reader["Column4"]) + "," + reader["Column5"];

                            using (FileStream fsWDT = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                            using(StreamWriter swDT = new StreamWriter(fsWDT))
                            {
                                //write csv line to file.
                                swDT.WriteLine(csvDetails.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //error handling here.
                myDEConnection.Close();
                return;
            }
            myDEConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error handling here.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now, this was working fine when I was using it with a 3rd party SQLite-based database, but the output I'm getting after modifing this to my MSSQL db looks something like this (ITEM1 is the primary key, a standard auto-incrementing ID-field):

```
ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3,ITEM4,ITEM5
1,row1_item2,row1_item3,row1_item4,row1_item5
1,row1_item2,row1_item3,row1_item4,row1_item5
1,row1_item2,row1_item3,row1_item4,row1_item5
1,row1_item2,row1_item3,row1_item4,row1_item5
1,row1_item2,row1_item3,row1_item4,row1_item5
1,row1_item2,row1_item3,row1_item4,row1_item5
2,row2_item2,row2_item3,row2_item4,row2_item5
2,row2_item2,row2_item3,row2_item4,row2_item5
2,row2_item2,row2_item3,row2_item4,row2_item5
2,row2_item2,row2_item3,row2_item4,row2_item5
2,row2_item2,row2_item3,row2_item4,row2_item5
3,row3_item2,row3_item3,row3_item4,row3_item5
3,row3_item2,row3_item3,row3_item4,row3_item5
3,row3_item2,row3_item3,row3_item4,row3_item5
3,row3_item2,row3_item3,row3_item4,row3_item5
....
```

So it seems that it writes several entries of the same row, where I would just like one single line each row. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

edit: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: I think your                            using(StreamWriter swDT = new StreamWriter(fsWDT))
                            {
                                //write csv line to file.
                                swDT.WriteLine(csvDetails.ToString());
                            } line needs to sit outside your for loop.

If I'm right the for loop should be working out the columns to write, but you have hard written these in.  Build up the line in your for loop and then write out the result outside this loop.

Comment: Opening and closing a file stream are expensive operations. Don't do that on each iteration. Open the stream once at the beginning and close only at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop isn't needed in the section below. Because it loops from 0 to FieldCount I assume the loop was originally meant to append the text from each column together but inside the loop there's a single line that concatenates the text and assigns it to csvDetails.

```
        try
        {
            reader = myDECommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    if(reader["Column1"].ToString() == "") {
                        //does nothing if the current line is "bugged" (containing no values at all, typically happens after reboot of 3rd party equipment).
                    }
                    else {
                        //grab relevant tag data and set the csv line for the current row.
                        string csvDetails = reader["Column1"] + "," + reader["Column2"] + "," + String.Format("{0:0.0}", reader["Column3"]) + "," + String.Format("{0:0.000}", reader["Column4"]) + "," + reader["Column5"];

                        using (FileStream fsWDT = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                        using(StreamWriter swDT = new StreamWriter(fsWDT))
                        {
                            //write csv line to file.
                            swDT.WriteLine(csvDetails.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was basing the read SQL part from another snippet I wrote to grab all column data, not just specified ones. Seems that slipped my mind. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have a for loop which is looping over the fieldcount.

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
```

I think it will work if you remove the loop as you don't need to iterate through the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we use *specialy designed export/import utilites* for dumping data.
However, if you have to implement you own routine I suggest *decomposing*.

```
private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SourceData(String sql) {
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHere)) {
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
          //TODO: you may want to add additional conditions here

          yield return reader; 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

private static IEnumerable<String> ToCsv(IEnumerable<IDataRecord> data) {
  foreach (IDataRecord record in data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < record .FieldCount; ++i) {
      String chunk = Convert.ToString(record .GetValue(0));

      if (i > 0)
        sb.Append(','); 

      if (chunk.Contains(',') || chunk.Contains(';'))
        chunk = "\"" + chunk.Replace("\"", "\"\"") +  "\"";

      sb.Append(chunk);
    }

    yield return sb.ToString(); 
  } 
}
```

Having `SourceData` and `ToCsv` you can easily implement

```
private static void WriteMyCsv(String fileName) {
  var source = SourceData("SELECT * FROM table");

  File.WriteAllLines(fileName, ToCsv(source));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens because output placed inside for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
```

and every record repeats FieldCount-times

Answer (score 0):

Complete example. Verified working .NET 4.8, May 22. Code simplified for demo.

Why the DataTable ? Under circumstances it is useful. If you converting hundreds of files at once and multi threading - it works as large buffer + you can do pretty complex data mangling at the same time - should you need it.

UNFORTUNATELY - Microsoft trying to detect the column types and if your data not comply with the mechanism it ends with hard to correct errors. In that case use the second solution.

```
// Get the data from SQLite
SqliteConnection SQLiDataCon = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\sqlite.db3");
SQLiDataCon.Open();     
SqliteDataReader SQLiDtaReader = new SqliteCommand(@"SELECT * FROM stats;", SQLiDataCon).ExecuteReader();

// Load data to DataTable
DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();
csvTable.Load(SQLiDtaReader);

// Get "one" string with column names
string csvFields = @"""" + String.Join(@""",""",csvTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName).ToArray()) + @"""";

// Prep "in memory the entire content of the CSV"  
StringBuilder csvString = new StringBuilder();

// Write the header in 
csvString.AppendLine(csvFields);

// Write the rows in 
foreach (DataRow dr in csvTable.Rows)
{
    csvString.AppendLine(@"""" + String.Join(@""",""", dr.ItemArray) + @"""");
}

// Save to file 
StreamWriter csvFile = new StreamWriter(@"c:\stats.csv");
csvFile.Write(csvString);
```

Without DataTable.

```
// SQLITE
SqliteConnection SQLiDataCon = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\sqlite.db3");
SQLiDataCon.Open();   

StringBuilder csvString = new StringBuilder();
StreamWriter csvFile;
Object[] csvRow;
SqliteDataReader  SQLiDtaReader = new SqliteCommand(@"SELECT * FROM sometable;", SQLiDataCon).ExecuteReader();

// CSV HEADER
csvString.AppendLine(@"""" + String.Join(@""",""", SQLiDtaReader.GetSchemaTable().AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("ColumnName")).ToArray<string>()) + @"""");

// CSV BODY  
while (SQLiDtaReader.Read())
{
    SQLiDtaReader.GetValues(csvRow = new Object[SQLiDtaReader.FieldCount]);
    csvString.AppendLine(@"""" + String.Join(@""",""",csvRow ) + @"""");
}

// WRITE IT 
csvFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\somecsvfile.csv");
csvFile.Write(csvString);
```